# androidでExoPlayerで動画再生すると90度回転して再生されます。

Tags: android

android4.4で動画再生すると、90度回転して再生されます。
android8は正常に再生されます。

exoplayerのバージョンは2.11.4です。
com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.11.4

android4.4で正常に再生するにはどうすればよろしいでしょうか？
アドバイスをよろしくお願いいたします。

```
public class VideoView extends FrameLayout {

  private HandlerWrapper mHandler;
  private Uri mUri;
  private SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
  private SimpleExoPlayer mMediaPlayer;

  public VideoView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(null, 0);
  }

  public VideoView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(attrs, 0);
  }

  public VideoView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init(attrs, defStyle);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
    releaseMediaPlayer();
    super.onDetachedFromWindow();
  }

  public void setHandler(HandlerWrapper handler) {
    mHandler = handler;
  }

  public void setUri(Uri uri) {
    mUri = uri;
  }

  public void play() {
    if (mMediaPlayer == null)
      return;
    mMediaPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
  }

  public void pause() {
    if (mMediaPlayer == null)
      return;
    mMediaPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(false);
  }

  public void seekTo(long position) {
    if (mMediaPlayer == null)
      return;
    mMediaPlayer.seekTo(position);
  }

  public boolean isPlaying() {
    return mMediaPlayer != null &&
           mMediaPlayer.getPlaybackState() != Player.STATE_ENDED &&
           mMediaPlayer.getPlaybackState() != Player.STATE_IDLE  &&
           mMediaPlayer.getPlayWhenReady();
  }

  private void init(AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    mSurfaceView = new SurfaceView(getContext());
    mSurfaceView.setZOrderOnTop(true);
    addView(mSurfaceView, 1, 1);
    mSurfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
      @Override
      public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        DefaultLoadControl loadControl = new DefaultLoadControl.Builder()
                                           .setPrioritizeTimeOverSizeThresholds(false)
                                           .createDefaultLoadControl();
        mMediaPlayer = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(getContext())
                         .setLoadControl(loadControl)
                         .build();
        mMediaPlayer.setVideoSurfaceHolder(holder);
        Context context = getContext();
        DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(context,
                                                 Util.getUserAgent(context, context.getPackageName()));
        MediaSource videoSource = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                                    .createMediaSource(mUri);
        mMediaPlayer.addVideoListener(new VideoListener() {
          @Override
          public void onVideoSizeChanged(int width, int height, int unappliedRotationDegrees, float pixelWidthHeightRatio) {
            layoutSurfaceView(width, height);
          }
        });
        mMediaPlayer.addListener(new EventListener() {
          private boolean mReady;
          @Override
          public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
          }
          @Override
          public void onIsPlayingChanged(boolean isPlaying) {
          }
          @Override
          public void onPlayerError(ExoPlaybackException error) {
          }
        });
        mMediaPlayer.prepare(videoSource);
      }
      @Override
      public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {}
      @Override
      public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        releaseMediaPlayer();
      }
    });
  }

  private void releaseMediaPlayer() {
    if (mMediaPlayer == null)
      return;
    mMediaPlayer.release();
    mMediaPlayer = null;
  }

  private void layoutSurfaceView(int width, int height) {
    if (mMediaPlayer == null)
      return;
    float radio = Math.min((float)getWidth() / (float)width, (float)getHeight() / (float)height);
    LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams)mSurfaceView.getLayoutParams();
    params.width   = (int)Math.floor(width  * radio);
    params.height  = (int)Math.floor(height * radio);
    params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    mSurfaceView.requestLayout();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自己レスです。
SurfaceViewをTextureViewに変更して、onVideoSizeChangedイベントのunappliedRotationDegreesをみて、必要に応じて回転することで解決しました。

```
mMediaPlayer.addVideoListener(new VideoListener() {
  @Override
  public void onVideoSizeChanged(int width, int height, int unappliedRotationDegrees, float pixelWidthHeightRatio) {
    int viewWidth  = getWidth();
    int viewHeight = getHeight();
    Matrix transform = new Matrix();
    float pivotX = (float)viewWidth  / 2.0f;
    float pivotY = (float)viewHeight / 2.0f;
    if (unappliedRotationDegrees == 90 || unappliedRotationDegrees == 270) {
      transform.postRotate(unappliedRotationDegrees, pivotX, pivotY);
      float radio = Math.min((float)viewWidth / (float)height, (float)viewHeight / (float)width);
      transform.postScale((float)height * radio / (float)viewHeight,
                          (float)width  * radio / (float)viewWidth, pivotX, pivotY);
    } else {
      float radio = Math.min((float)viewWidth / (float)width, (float)viewHeight / (float)height);
      transform.postScale((float)width  * radio / (float)viewWidth,
                          (float)height * radio / (float)viewHeight, pivotX, pivotY);
    }
    mTextureView.setTransform(transform);
  }
});
```